# How to force Search and Promote returns JSON format instead of xml?

Tags: json, search-engine, aem, transport, search-and-promote

In our application we send requests to S&P like this:

```
http://SearchAndPromoteUrl/?parameter1=1&parameter2=2
```

My current understanding that S&P is external cloud service. sometimes we collect statistic and send to the server. Server analyzes our feed and we can get niformation from this S&P server.

1.Where can I found valid parameters after  `http://SearchAndPromoteUrl/?`

2.Which manipulations should I execute for getting JSON instead of XML(S&P server should returns JSON Now our S&P returns xml).

[This article](http://cqsearchpromote.blogspot.ru/2013/11/comparison-between-xml-vs-html-vs-json.html) says that it is possible

**related information**

http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/snp/8.15.0/SPguide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd suggest using the updated documentation - https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/snp/8.16.0/c_getting_started.html

1. The recommended way to integrate with S&P is to use the search form they provide. This form takes care of the request and parameters for you.

UPDATE: Here are more details: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/snp/t_copying_the_html_code_of_the_search_form_into_the_pages_of_your_website.html

2. Yes, you can use JSON instead of the standard XML response, and it's quite simple: just write your own presentation template using JSON instead of XML (see https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/snp/8.16.0/c_about_templates.html)

Have a nice day.

Comment: *to use the search form they provide* - can you clarify this phrase?

Comment: I am not sure that write whole presentation template for json for mat is so simple